# I have menustrip and each of items have its combobox

Tags: c#, fill, sqldatareader, menustrip

I have menustrip and each of items have its combobox.
At runtime I want combos to be loaded from sql database tables.
I tried dataadapter but at runtime all combos are in blank.
Please help me in this topic.

Comment: Show some evidence of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Hum...If you're using something support databinding, Maybe you can use the MVVM-like pattern.

1.Build a Model for your database tables, you need some thing to store the states.

```
public class CheckState
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public CheckState(bool isChecked)
    {
        this.IsChecked = isChecked;
    }
}


public class Model
{
    public bool[] CheckStates { get; set; }
}
```

2.ViewModel should be something like this.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged //this is important
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private Model model;
    public List<CheckState> checkStates = new List<CheckState>();
    public List<CheckState> CheckStates
    {
        get { return checkStates; }
        set
        {
            checkStates = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CheckStates"); //And this is important
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        InitializeModel();
    }

    private void InitializeModel()
    {
        //here to retrieve data from your database
        model = new Model
                    {
                        CheckStates = new[] { true, false, true, false }
                    };
        foreach(var stateItem in model.CheckStates)
        {
            this.checkStates.Add(new CheckState(stateItem));
        }
    }
}
```

3.And fill the Model's properties when you initialize your ViewModel.

```
    public void InitilizeModelData()
    {
        // In gernal, the data comes from database
        var model = new CaculatorModel()
        {
            IsChecked = True,
        };

        IsChecked = model.IsChecked;
    }
```

4.Set your UI. Binding your checkBox's isChecked property to the ViewModel's IsChecked property.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new ViewModel(); //And this is also important
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

And the XML:(Please try to figure out the relation between father & child)

```
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding CheckStates}">
        <Menu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"></CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Menu.ItemTemplate>
    </Menu>
```

### OK, I'm Talking Too Much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you instruct me something unrelated to my question.
Data must be called from sql database.
I attach the shape of my form.
The target combobox name is cmbCement and previous menu is tsmCement.
I am not sure adding Items in property will be suitable to my form goal.

public void FrmInterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server = .\\SQLEXPRESS ; DataBase = Badban; Integrated Security                          = true");
       con.Open();


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SelectCement", con);
        SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("SelectCement",con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmbCement.DroppedDown.Add(dt.Tables[0].Rows);
            cmbCement.ComboBox.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
            cmbCement.ComboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
            cmbCement.ComboBox.Text = "Name";   

            con.Close();
        }
```